# Bind click to control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
count=1;
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
   count++;
   $("#ImageProductLeft"+count.toString()).bind('click', function(){
           alert(i);                                                                                                                                    
   });
}
```

I want that when click on `ImageProductLeft1` show `alert(1)` and click on `ImageProductLeft2` show `alert(2)` and ...

But `onclick` on all `ImageProductLeft1` show `alert(5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count=1;
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
   count++;
   $("#ImageProductLeft"+count.toString()).bind('click', {i: i}, function(event){
         alert(event.data.i);
   });
}
```

Comment: VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY TANKS.GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOD

Comment: When you bind the click handler, the current i will be stored as data to the function. At the moment when the function is called the for-loop has finished and i has the value 5. In your version he alerts this 5, in my version he alerts the stored value.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a function in a a loop (closures). All variables will be shared between them, also `i`.

When the functions are called eventually, the loop already finished and `i` will have the value `5`.

JavaScript does not have block scope. To create a new scope and capture the value of the variables you make a function call:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
   (function(x) {
       $("#ImageProductLeft"+count.toString()).bind('click', function(){
           alert(x);                                                                                                                                    
       });
   }(i));
}
```

Here we use an immediate function to "capture" the value of `i`.

---

That said, as you are using jQuery, there are other, more elegant methods to solve this, as shown in [@scessor's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895094/bind-click-to-control/6895143#6895143) and [@Shadow Wizard's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895094/bind-click-to-control/6895182#6895182) answers.

Nevertheless, it is important to know *why* it works like this and *how* it can be solved in "pure" JavaScript.

Closures can be tricky. I suggest having a look at [JavaScript Closures for Dummies](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is bit more elegant and flexible:

```
$("div[id^='ImageProductLeft']").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        alert(index);
    });
});
```

You can have as much elements starting with `ImageProductLeft` as you want, and clicking any will alert their respective index.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/59ubR/).

Comment: Thanks Felix, you got my +1 already for great and full answer, as usual. :)

Comment: Seeing those loops made me feel a bit ill. Glad someone posted the proper answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i<6; i++)
{
    $("#ImageProductLeft" + i.toString()).bind('click', function() {
        alert(i);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having this problem because the `i` in each of the event handlers you created is pointing to the same location in memory. Try using this:

```
count=1;
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
   count++;

   $("#ImageProductLeft"+count.toString()).bind('click', 
       function(x){
           return function() { alert(x); };
       }(i)                                                                                                                                    
   });
}
```

This is a rather common mistake. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake) for further explanation